# Making a div exactly fit the children when the children are position:absolute

Tags: html, css, positioning

I was trying to see if I could get layout to work something like what graphviz does when it groups nodes. Essentially, I can position nodes in whatever location and then lay out a box around those with a dotted outline.

So I had some HTML like this:

```
<div class="graph">
    <div class="group" id="group1">
        <div class="node" id="node1">1</div>
        <div class="node" id="node2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group" id="group2">
        <div class="node" id="node3">3</div>
        <div class="node" id="node4">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the position of the nodes to be the main thing I'm controlling. I figured out that I could use absolute positioning for both, at the cost of having to do maths on the position of the nodes, because they become relative to the group. So I end up with CSS like this:

```
div.graph {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0;
}
div.group {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
div.node {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  height: 20pt;
  padding: 0;
}
#group1 { left: 20pt; top: 20pt; height: 40pt; }
#group2 { left: 50pt; top: 60pt; height: 40pt; }
#node1 { left: /*20-20=*/0pt; top: /*20-20=*/0pt; }
#node2 { left: /*200-20=*/180pt; top: /*40-20=*/20pt; }
#node3 { left: /*50-50=*/0pt; top: /*60-60=*/0pt; }
#node4 { left: /*800-50=*/750pt; top: /*80-60=*/20pt; }
```

The result of this can be seen on the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYgaZ/1/) I was using to try and fix it.

Essentially, the bit I can't figure out is the width of the groups. I don't know how wide the nodes are going to be because the contents are variable. I tried using 100% as a compromise but it didn't go 100% of the width anyway, once a horizontal scrollbar is involved. Ideally there would be a way to get it to end exactly on the right hand side of the node (later I can work out the padding situation... at the moment it's set to 0 for everything.)

I didn't want to use JavaScript to figure out the width dynamically because I was worried about having to cope with the width changing.

If all else fails I might just have to use SVG but I have various issues over in SVG as well (text layout isn't as convenient as it is in HTML.)

Comment: The problem has to do with how the CSS formatting model works.  Absolutely positioned elements to not contribute to the computed width or height of the containing block element.  Therefore, you can't get the effect that you want with the current HTML/CSS.  You may have to rethink your approach and use relative positioning and margins or way of setting the with of `.group` based on the node positions.  This is a challenging problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with absolute positioning. As per the spec,

> [In the absolute positioning model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning), a box is removed from the normal
>   flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings) and assigned a
>   position with respect to a containing block.

Your best bet is using floats and margins: http://jsfiddle.net/WspTQ/

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="c">
        <div class="x"></div>
        <div class="y"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="c">
        <div class="x"></div>
        <div class="y"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.a, .b {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background:#eee
}
.x, .y {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:black
}
.x {
    margin-bottom:-50px
}
.a .y {
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:20px
}
.b .y {
    margin-top:75px;
    margin-left:150px
}
```

Comment: Margins on the groups are the offset from the top-left and margins on the nodes are the negative offset from the top-left of the group? It's hard to tell by reading and you didn't maintain the commented calculations I had in the original which illustrated where the numbers came from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you well. But try this:

```
div.group {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green;
  width: auto;
  min-width: ;// if you need one;
  max-width: ;// if you need one;
  padding: 0;
}
```